# Древляние: от слова "дерево" или от слова "древний"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Всегда было интересно: название славянского народа древляне происходит от слова "дерево" или от слова "древний"? Если второе, то, выходит, что это не самоназвание? Или слова "древний" и "дерево" родственные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Название "древляне" произошло   от  лесистой местности обитания. В летописи сказано: 
"Также и эти славяне пришли и сели по Днепру и назвались полянами, а другие — древлянами, потому что сели в лесах..."

А по происхождению эти два слова, возможно, исторические родственники, восходящие к одной праиндоевропеской основе.

Comment: Похоже. Тем более, что древняя (простите зза каламбур) форма "древний" - древлий.

Comment: Фасмер подтверждает: Древний: Ст.-слав. древл^ьн^ь, древьн^ь. Дальнейшая этимология: Возм., из *dreuёos, ср. гот. triggws "верный", греч. DroТn † „scurТn (Гесихий), а также лит. dre~ve† "дуплистый ствол дерева, улей", лтш. dreve "улей, выдолбленное дерево"; другая ступень вокализма: лит. drave†ґti "выдалбливать", drove†~, dro~ve† "дуплистое дерево"; см. Буга, РФВ 67, 236 и сл.; Далее сюда же гот. triu "дерево", русск.дерево, здоровый; см. Остхоф (там же)